# Closing parentheses in string dropped when creating app service app setting via Azure cli

Tags: powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

I'm creating an Application Setting in an Azure App Service via the Azure cli. The value of the setting is a KeyVault reference which, if you're not familiar, has a special syntax:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://something.vault.azure.net/secrets/SomeKey/xxxxxxxxxx)
```

My powershell script creates the KeyVault secret and stores the secret id. I then construct the Application Setting value like:

```
$new_secret_id = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=$secret_id)"
```

I use `Write-Host` to verify `$new_secret_id` is exactly correct at this point.

Then I use the following command to create the Application Setting but the trailing paren is always missing and that causes the app setting to become a verbatim value instead of a KeyVault reference. If I hard-code a value instead of using the variable `$secret_id` it works, it does not strip the closing `)`.

```
az webapp config appsettings set `
    --resource-group $rg `
    --name $app_name `
    --settings A_SECRET=$new_secret_id
```

[image]

> Update

I've been trying with various combinations of values for `$secred_id`. It only seems to happen when the value is a URL.

Comment: Does it work if you enclose your `--settings` parameter in double quote ?
`--settings "A_SECRET=$new_secret_id"` instead of `--settings A_SECRET=$new_secret_id`

Comment: @SagePourpre I'll give it a try at work tomorrow.

Comment: @Crowcoder What @SagePourpre said is right, we need to use ```''``` or ```""``` to warp the value.

Comment: @SagePourpre that made no difference. The `)` is still dropped. I also tried `A_SECRET="$new_secret_id"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is already a documented problem (feature):

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/8506

> We made this change to help prevent the shell from interpreting the special characters in the setting value

As noted in the github comments, you can embed double quotes.

`--settings "A_SECRET=""@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=$secret_id)"""`